# Redefine (or define) Keyboard shorcuts in the VB6 IDE?

Tags: ide, vb6

Is it possible to redefine keyboard shortcuts in the Visual Basic 6 IDE?
Specifically, I want to redefine the "Definition" and "Last Position"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redefine at least some shorcuts using [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/) for VB6

Answer (score 0):

Not from the IDE, as far as I know.